# Sometimes my files become corrupt while copying to USB

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive

I bought a new USB . Sometimes when i copy paste the files , then i try to run it from USB it gives file is corrupt or archieve is corrupt.

WIth text files when i open from USB sometimes some garbage characters appear instead of original text.

What can be the reason

Comment: A new USB what? Is it solid state or a spinning disk?

Comment: @Anonymous I wondered too, but then I saw the usb-flash-drive tag.

I'm thinking either reformat or dead out of the box.

Comment: It was the new USB , i bought from ebay 32GB from hong kong.
I tried formatiing it but same thing happens

Comment: Never *ever* buy any flash memory from ebay, there's more fake than real on there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are times that hardware is tested at the factory as satisfactory but due to shipping, handling or storage can become damaged if not outright broken. I've had this happen with high-end xeon servers, external usb hard drives and even memory. There's way too many times this has happened at work or at home. Simply package up the device, call in a service ticket with the manufacturer and send the product back for a replacement. Or if you still have a reciept and it has been 30 days or less since purchasing the item, take it back to the place you bought it from unless it's an online purchase, and they will replace the item with something of equal value and specs.

But yeah, this stuff happens for we are not dealing with rubber and wood, these technologies tend to have quirks at times.

Answer (score 0):

Which operating system do you use?

Often there is a problem with the encoding or character set.

If you're using a *nix OS put **iocharset=utf8** something similar to your **etc/fstab**

`/dev/sr1 /media/WD\040SmartWare udf ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1001,gid=100,umask=77,iocharset=utf8 0 0`

Comment: that kind of misconfiguration won't corrupt a file, just a filename.

Answer (score 0):

Besides hardware faults, there can also be other causes to such a problem :

1. A too-old chipset driver in your computer
2. The USB enclosure does not fully conform in its specs to whatever your computer expects

If replacing the new USB disk to the same brand and model doesn't fix the problem, you might try buying some other brand (better google first for reviews). You should also search if a newer chipset driver exists (but take **great** care when updating it).